# sputnikdao2 - ChangePolicy - "data did not match any variant of untagged enum VersionedPolicy"

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to change the policy for a deployed sputnikdao2 contract.

I am getting this error:

```
   "ExecutionError":"`Smart contract panicked: panicked at 'Failed to deserialize input from JSON.: Error(\"data did not match any variant of untagged enum VersionedPolicy\", line: 1, column: 423)', src/proposals.rs:384:1`"
},
"transaction_outcome":{
   "block_hash":"8aUiGxnJv12BASyKjPKVsYWegEmbH8Lz1LsXu7gGXFwa",
   "id":"FTTFLVZzzrK7CT6KCNqWVCs67Hc5oBRHBT9TqCciqjY6",
   "outcome":{
      "executor_id":"hundred.testnet",
      "gas_burnt":2428900339092,
      "logs":[
         
      ],
      "receipt_ids":[
         "EuNWubtxcY9YjcbTxSwrrYj59GBVj8u6a8RktQj7tHSh"
      ],
      "status":{
         "SuccessReceiptId":"EuNWubtxcY9YjcbTxSwrrYj59GBVj8u6a8RktQj7tHSh"
      },
      "tokens_burnt":"242890033909200000000"
   },
   "proof":[
      {
         "direction":"Left",
         "hash":"9eTyjRrHrNP1Bmw4rDgSouGmvxP7Lg3EaoUn15qBQH3h"
      },
      {
         "direction":"Right",
         "hash":"4NLf8mPom49oVbXmB2ouujxctjbyZC5FBi5ny1NFcXYj"
      }
   ]
}
}
```

you can see more information here :
https://gist.github.com/hiba-machfej/3a681d22fc2310966ca7692ec3a189d2

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to send this:

```
'{"proposal": {"description": "Add New Council", "kind": {"ChangePolicy": { "policy": { "roles": [{ "name": "all", "kind": "Everyone", "permissions": [ "*:AddProposal" ], "vote_policy": "{}"}], "default_vote_policy": { "weight_kind": "RoleWeight", "quorum": "0", "threshold": [ 1, 2 ] }, "proposal_bond": "1000000000000000000000000", "proposal_period": "604800000000000", "bounty_bond": "1000000000000000000000000", "bounty_forgiveness_period": "86400000000000"}}}}}' \
--accountId hundred.testnet \
--amount 1
```

I re-wrote the objects again and it worked:

```
'{"proposal": {"description": "Add New Council", "kind": {"ChangePolicy": { "policy": {  "roles": [{ "name": "all", "kind": "Everyone", "permissions": ["*:AddProposal", "*:Finalize"], "vote_policy": {}}], "default_vote_policy": { "weight_kind": "RoleWeight", "quorum": "0", "threshold": [ 1, 2 ]}, "proposal_bond": "1000000000000000000000000", "proposal_period": "604800000000000", "bounty_bond": "1000000000000000000000000", "bounty_forgiveness_period": "86400000000000" }}}}}' \
--accountId hundred.testnet \
--amount 1
```

This is the recipt:
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/DxXLUUcx2jcLdoCFT2HbhSinWV6zjSREUkNXnN3kkHD4

I think there was an error in json format in the first code I was running.